# selecting all rows after a condition, multple times, on filtered/groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'game': [20101,20101,20101,20101,20101,20101,20101,60734,60734,60734,60734,60734,60734,60734],
                   'hit': ['n','n','n','y','n','y','n','n','n','n','y','n','n','n'],
                   'score':[2,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,3,4,2,3,3,1]
                   },)

    game    hit score
0   20101   n   2
1   20101   n   1
2   20101   n   0
3   20101   y   2
4   20101   n   1
5   20101   y   0
6   20101   n   2
7   60734   n   0
8   60734   n   3
9   60734   n   4
10  60734   y   2
11  60734   n   3
12  60734   n   3
13  60734   n   1
```

i am trying to select all rows starting from the first 'y' in the hit column, and sum scores.
which i managed with

```
hit_index = np.where(df.hit.eq('y'))[0][0]
after_hit = df.iloc[hit_index:]
after_hit.score.sum()
```

But i want the sum per game.
I tried looping through games with code above, but the `np.where` code says `'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'`
I tried many messy things with `groupby` but cant fathom how to integrate with `where`.
To clarify, I would like the sum of score, for all rows below, and including the first hit, **for each individual game**. Thanks in advance.

```
    game    score_sum_after_hit
0   20101   5
1   60734   9
```

Also - I will eventually need to record the sums after second hit, third etc. so am disinclined to add a new column marking rows down as 'after 1st hit'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = df.groupby("game")[["hit", "score"]].apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[(x["hit"] == "y").cumsum() > 0, "score"].sum()
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
game
20101    5
60734    9
dtype: int64
```

---

Or: as a dataframe:

```
x = (
    df.groupby("game")[["hit", "score"]]
    .apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x["hit"] == "y").cumsum() > 0, "score"].sum())
    .to_frame()
    .rename(columns={0: "score_sum_after_hit"})
)
print(x)

       score_sum_after_hit
game                      
20101                    5
60734                    9
```

Comment: bingo, thanks a lot. what is this bit for ?  '.cumsum() > 0'

Comment: @Studiace `(x["hit"] == "y").cumsum() > 0` This will find every `y` in `hit` (boolean array)  and then do cumulative sum from it ... so something like `0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ...` and then selects only non-zero values from them.